# Фильтрация в запросе SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Все привет! Выгружаю из mssql базы 1С данные о сотрудниках компании: ФИО, должность. При присоединении должности, начинают дублироваться записи, так как сотрудник получал повышение, а старя должность так и лежит в базе. Есть поле _Period, в котором записывается дата обновления должности. Вопрос состоит в том, как оставить только должность с последним изменением даты? ТО есть самую свежую должность.

У меня уже есть запрос, который выводит ФИО, время и должность. Выглядит это так:

```
Select u._IDRRef as ID, u._Description as ФИО,
       max(t._Period) as Время_обновления, k._Description as Должность
FROM [edo].[dbo].[_InfoRg10036] as t 
LEFT JOIN [edo].[dbo].[_Reference73X1] as k on k._IDRRef = t._Fld10040RRef
LEFT JOIN [edo].[dbo].[_Reference123X1] as u on t._Fld10039RRef = u._IDRRef
WHERE u._Fld5319 = 0x00
GROUP BY u._IDRRef, u._Description, k._Description
ORDER BY u._Description
```

Запрос еще будет выводить эл. почту и телефон.

Вот результат работы моего запроса. Как можно увидеть, у человека разные должности. Мне же нужно оставить только должность от 4021.06.11 (Такую дату формирует 1С, я тут не при чем).
[image: Результат работы запроса]

Собственно, как оставить строку с должностью, где дата будет максимальная?

P.S. В sql я не очень сильно шарю и пока не очень его понимаю. Вы очень сильно мне поможете, если подскажите, как это сделать или отправите какой-нибудь похожий пример или даже решение моего вопроса. А то уже второй день пошел, а я все борюсь с этой уникальностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, у меня получилось сделать то, что мне нужно где то с 20 попытки.
Возможно мой запрос и не очень красивый, но оно работает.
Думаю кому то он будет полезным.

```
SELECT t._Period, u._Description as ФИО, k._Description as Должность  FROM [edo].[dbo].[_InfoRg10036] as t 
LEFT JOIN [edo].[dbo].[_Reference73X1] as k on k._IDRRef = t._Fld10040RRef
LEFT JOIN [edo].[dbo].[_Reference123X1] as u on t._Fld10039RRef = u._IDRRef
LEFT JOIN [edo].[dbo].[_Reference123_VT5340X1] as cEm on cEm._Reference123_IDRRef = u._IDRRef  and cEm._KeyField = 0x00000001
LEFT JOIN [edo].[dbo].[_Reference123_VT5340X1] as cPh on cPh._Reference123_IDRRef = u._IDRRef  and cPh._KeyField = 0x00000002
WHERE t._Period = (SELECT MAX(tt._Period) FROM [edo].[dbo].[_InfoRg10036] as tt WHERE t._Fld10039RRef = tt._Fld10039RRef) and u._Fld5319 = 0x00 and cEm._Fld5344 is Not null
ORDER BY t._Fld10039RRef
```

Если есть какие то замечания, то они будут очень полезными для меня и я приму их к сведению, так как только начинаю профессионально работать с базами!